# Bug using kivy with Python

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently making a project of a calculator using kivy, I downloaded it but I can not run my code and I don't know why it seems to have a problem with the interpretor even if Kivy is install and I cheked it  it says":

```
C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/MAX/Desktop/pythonProject/calculatrice/main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\MAX\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-06-29_42.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\33661\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\33661\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7927'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 26.20.100.7927'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 235, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
 
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\calculatrice\main.py", line 74, in <module>
     app.run()
   File "C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\calculatrice\main.py", line 27, in build
     button = Button(
   File "C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 121, in __init__
     super(ButtonBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 317, in __init__
     super(Label, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\MAX\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 357, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 238, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: Properties ['text_'] passed to __init__ may not be existing property names. Valid properties are ['always_release', 'anchors', 'background_color', 'background_disabled_down', 'background_disabled_normal', 'background_down', 'background_normal', 'base_direction', 'bold', 'border', 'center', 'center_x', 'center_y', 'children', 'cls', 'color', 'disabled', 'disabled_color', 'disabled_outline_color', 'ellipsis_options', 'font_blended', 'font_context', 'font_family', 'font_features', 'font_hinting', 'font_kerning', 'font_name', 'font_size', 'halign', 'height', 'ids', 'is_shortened', 'italic', 'last_touch', 'line_height', 'markup', 'max_lines', 'min_state_time', 'mipmap', 'motion_filter', 'opacity', 'outline_color', 'outline_width', 'padding', 'padding_x', 'padding_y', 'parent', 'pos', 'pos_hint', 'refs', 'right', 'shorten', 'shorten_from', 'size', 'size_hint', 'size_hint_max', 'size_hint_max_x', 'size_hint_max_y', 'size_hint_min', 'size_hint_min_x', 'size_hint_min_y', 'size_hint_x', 'size_hint_y', 'split_str', 'state', 'strikethrough', 'strip', 'text', 'text_language', 'text_size', 'texture', 'texture_size', 'top', 'underline', 'unicode_errors', 'valign', 'width', 'x', 'y']"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow, please post your code so we can find the error, thank you.

Comment: Looks like in your `build()` method you are trying to create a `Button` in the line that starts `button = Button(`. Perhaps you are passing `text_="some text"`. The `text_` is not a supported property of a `Button`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.